# Why is evaluation Enter for Mac and shift+Enter for Windows?

Tags: evaluation, keyboard

Per the title, why is evaluation done using just the Enter key for Macintosh and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for Windows?

UPDATE

Okay, I see the Mac keyboard's <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is actually labeled "Return", so by <kbd>Enter</kbd> we mean the numeric keypad <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I use Enter key on window to evaluate a cell. Never used SHIFT+ENTER (use the enter key on the number keypad, on the far rightside of the keyboard) not the one return one.

Comment: On my Mac, it's Shift+Enter.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus No, it's Shift + Return == Enter :)

Comment: @rm-rf: Oops, you're right haha

Answer (score 5):

Evaluation works the same way on Mac, Linux and Windows.

The main Enter key ([called Return on Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key#Differences_between_Enter_and_Return), but found in the same keyboard position) adds a newline.

Shift-Enter (Shift-Return) evaluates the cell.

The Enter key found on the numeric keypad (called Enter on Mac) also evaluates a cell.